# How do variable assignment with arrays behave in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the exact behavior of arrays in Javascript. I know that they work by reference. But I was confused when I came across this piece of code:

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3];

let arr2 = arr1;

arr1[2] = 4;

console.log(arr2); // [1,2,4]

arr1 = [2, 3, 4];

console.log(arr2); // [1,2,4] why not [2, 3, 4]
```

So how exactly do arrays behave in javascript?

Comment: That’s not a question about arrays, but about variables. When you write `arr1 = [2, 3, 4];`, a new array `[2, 3, 4]` is created and assigned to `arr1`. That new array has nothing to do with `arr2` or the other array anymore.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `let arr2 = arr1;` both variables share reference to same actual array.

However if you reassign one of those variables to a different array they no longer share same reference and are completely isolated from each other

Comment: Is this due to immutability nature?

Comment: No...has nothing to do with immutability. Simply a value change. The new value points to a completely different object(array)

Comment: @sv123 No, arrays are mutable. It's just the fact you're completely reassigning to a whole new array and thus a whole new reference (to array in memory)

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this, a variable is a pointer for an object in memory, now:

- Line 1: Assingned pointer (`arr1`) to object `[1,2,3]`
- Line 2: Assigned a pointer for a pointer which points to object `[1,2,3]`, this is what is meant by reference.
- Line 3: changed object `[1,2,3]`'s last value to `4`. At this point `arr1` and `arr2` still points to this object.
- Line 4: Assinged the pointer `arr1` a **NEW object** with content `[2,3,4]`. At this point `arr2` points still to the old `[1,2,4]` object.